# If statement fails in jest test for componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs

I am trying to test with jest if a method in componentDidUpdate is called once the id in react router is updated. I made a different test and I know that the lifecycle method is called but the if statement in it fails.

Method:

```
componentDidUpdate(){
if(this.id && this.props.match.params.id && this.id !== this.props.match.params.id){
  foo();
   }
}
```

jest test:

```
it("", () => {
  const wrapper = mount (<Component match={params:{id: "A"}} />, {lifecycleExperimental: true});
  const  inst = wrapper.instance();
  inst.foo = jest.fn();
  inst.id = "B";

  wrapper.setProps ({
  match: {
    params: { id: "C"}
      }
  });
   
   inst.forceUpdate();
   wrapper.update();

   expect(inst.foo).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The test results in numbers of calls: 0.

Comment: Define `inst.foo = ...` before you mount the component. Define all spy and variable. Then invoke necessary function to be tested and then validate. In your case, since mount is on first line, it'll render component before you initialize spy and hence 0 calls

Comment: For me, code looks correct. Can you try with following change.\n
const mockFunction = jest.fn();
inst.foo = mockFunction;
.
.
.
expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();

Comment: what is 'this.id'  and why do you use it two times in 'this.id && this.props.match.params.id && this.id '

Comment: What's `foo();`? Please [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The suggestions don't work sorry..